# how to write to shared memory in python from stream?

Tags: python, sockets, shared-memory

I have a processes from several servers that send data to my local port 2222 via udp every second.

I want to read this data and write it to shared memory so there can be other processes to read the data from shared memory and do things to it.

I've been reading about `mmap` and it seems I have to use a file... which I can't seem to understand why.

I have an `a.py` that reads the data from the socket, but how can I write it to an shm?

Once once it's written, I need to write `b.py`, `c.py`, `d.py`, etc., to read the very same shm and do things to it.

Any help or snippet of codes would greatly help.

Comment: If the data sharing is only going to be between Python processes, it might make sense to use the [`multprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. It has several synchronized data structures for you to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that what you're trying to build will require more than just shared memory: it's all well if `a.py` writes to shared memory, but how will `b.py` know when the memory is ready and can be read from?  All in all, it is often simpler to solve this problem by connecting the multiple processes not via shared memory, but through some other mechanism.

(The reason for why `mmap` usually needs a file name is that it needs a *name* to connect the several processes.  Indeed, if `a.py` and `b.py` both call `mmap()`, how would the system know that these two processes are asking for memory to be shared between them, and not some unrelated `z.py`?  Because they both `mmap`ed the same file.  There are also Linux-specific extensions to give a name that doesn't correspond to a *file* name, but it's more a hack IMHO.)

Maybe the most basic alternative mechanism is *pipes:* they are usually connected with the help of the shell when the programs are started.  That's how the following works (on Linux/Unix): `python a.py | python b.py`.  Any output that `a.py` sends goes to the pipe, whose other end is the input for `b.py`.  You'd write `a.py` so that it listens to the UDP socket and writes the data to stdout, and `b.py` so that it reads from stdin to process the data received.  If the data needs to go to several processes, you can use e.g. named pipes, which have a nice (but Bash-specific) syntax: `python a.py >(python b.py) >(python c.py)` will start `a.py` with two arguments, which are names of pseudo-files that can be opened and written to.  Whatever is written to the first pseudo-file goes as input for `b.py`, and similarly what is written to the second pseudo-file goes as input for `c.py`.

Answer (score 0):

`mmap` doesn't take a file name but rather a file descriptor. It performs the so-called memory mapping, i.e. it associates pages in the virtual memory space of the process with portions of the file-like object, represented by the file descriptor. This is a very powerful operation since it allows you:

- to access the content of a file simply as an array in memory;
- to access the memory of special I/O hardware, e.g. the buffers of a sound card or the framebuffer of a graphics adapter (this is possible since file desciptors in Unix are abstractions and they can also refer to device nodes instead of regular files);
- to share memory between processes by performing shared maps of the same object.

The old pre-POSIX way to use shared memory on Unix was to use the System V IPC shared memory. First a shared memory segment had to be created with `shmget(2)` and then attached to the process with `shmat(2)`. SysV shared memory segments (as well as other IPC objects) have no names but rather numeric IDs, so the special hash function `ftok(3)` is provided, which converts the combination of a pathname string and a project ID integer into a numeric key ID, but collisions are possible.

The modern POSIX way to use shared memory is to open a file-like memory object with `shm_open(2)`, resize it to the desired size with `ftruncate(2)` and then to `mmap(2)` it. Memory-mapping in this case acts like the `shmat(2)` call from the SysV IPC API and truncation is necessary since `shm_open(2)` creates objects with an initial size of zero.

(these are part of the C API; what Python modules provide is more or less thin wrappers around those calls and often have nearly the same signature)

It is also possible to get shared memory by memory mapping the same regular file in all processes that need to share memory. As a matter of fact, Linux implements the POSIX shared memory operations by creating files on a special `tmpfs` file system. The `tmpfs` driver implements very lightweight memory mapping by directly mapping the pages that hold the file content into the address space of the process that executes `mmap(2)`. Since `tmpfs` behaves as a normal filesystem, you can examine its content using `ls`, `cat` and other shell tools. You can even create shared memory objects this way or modify the content of the existent ones. The difference between a file in `tmpfs` and a regular filesystem file is that the latter is persisted to storage media (hard disk, network storage, flash drive, etc.) and occasionally changes are flushed to this storage media while the former lives entirely in RAM. Solaris also provides similar RAM-based filesystem, also called `tmpfs`.

In modern operating systems memory mapping is used extensively. Executable files are memory-mapped in order to supply the content of those pages, that hold the executable code and the static data. Also shared libraries are memory-mapped. This saves physical memory since these mappings are shared, e.g. the same physical memory that holds the content of an executable file or a shared library is mapped in the virtual memory space of each process.